# Tutorial for any new Facebook API Rails wrappers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebooker2

Is there a tutorial on any of the up-to-date (Nov 2010) Facebook (new API) wrappers for Rails such as Facebooker2 or Koala?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a tutorial for facebooker2 or Koala but I encorage you to take a look at [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem

Answer (score 0):

I have used Koala for Facebook integration, and definitely recommend it. If you are looking for an introduction on how to get started, I recommend checking out the project's Wiki on Github. It has some great Wiki articles on using the library.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki

Answer (score 0):

For my Facebook API projects, I use the following Graph API gem -
https://github.com/moomerman/facebook_oauth

They have a wonderful example app hosted at - 
http://facebook-oauth.heroku.com/

The wiki of the gem itself is pretty helpful.

If you are looking for any 3rd person perspective on using the library, then I'm not sure if you would find it since the WIKI of the gem itself is pretty explanatory and helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Depending of what you want to use it for, if its for facebook connect, there is 2 excellent railscast for integrating OAuth and Devise

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

The example is with twitter, but changing it to facebook takes only a change in a config file